# Define name of winForm that using the class? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods, development-environment

I am developing a project with 20 winforms in C#. These forms uses comman class named "databaseOperations".
My question is how can i define the winform name(sender) that using method in this class. I want to do something like that below;

```
public class databaseOperations
    {
        public void loadfile(string path)
        {
            //if (sender form.name== "FormA")
                 {// codes...........;}
            //else if (sender form.name== "FormB")
                 {// codes...........;}
            
        }
    }
```

I want to get name of winform.

Thanx in advance,

Comment: You make it a parameter of the method: `public void loadfile(string fromForm, string path) {}`.  Then you call it from each form like `theDataOperationsObject.LoadFrom(nameof(Form1), @"c:\path\file.ext")`

Comment: Take a look at [C# Naming Conventions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/) and [C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) and [C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

Comment: @OlivierRogier many many thanx man. i followed your solution and its worked. You saved me to writes huges codes. Thanx again.

Comment: I'm curious on why do you even need to know from which form came the call? Or what happens if it doesn't comes from a form?

Comment: @Alejandro thanx for your attention. Every form has datagridviews, and List<> classes.DataGridView and List results is saved on json file with using this comman class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard pattern is to define this method:

```
public void LoadFile(Form sender, string path)
```

Which we call like that:

```
var dbOps = new DatabaseOperations();

dbOps.LoadFile(myForm or this, "pathToFile");
```

Thus now we can check like that:

```
if ( sender.Name == "SomeName" )
{ 
  //...
}
```

Or anything else from the sender instance like for example:

```
sender.Tag

typeof(sender)
```

This last allows to make a difference between:

- `MyFormA`
- `MyFormB`
- And so on...

```
var typeSender = sender.GetType();
if ( typeSender == typeof(MyFormA) )
else
if ( typeSender == typeof(MyFormB) )
```

Also a switch can be used.

Instead of using a string name, so if is more robust and maintainable as strings can easily be change and we need to propagate that by hand, and this may cause big problems. Using types, refactoring tools do that for us.

But if several instances of `MyForm` can have differents `Name` property values, so we can check it, that's fine too, that just needs to take care.

Comment: Yeah, no. The above is terrible advice. No sign of polymorphism anywhere. A method outside one class (even a `Form`) shouldn't have to check the type or name of the object passed to it in order to selectively perform operations. The original question is way too vague to know what would actually be good here, but the above is _definitely_ not it.